# Не получается вывести период активности пользователей в группах. 1С Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь добавить в массив пользовательских полей значения принадлежности к группам и период активности пользователей в них.

```html
<?
global $USER;
$arfilter = Array(
            "ID" => $_REQUEST['MANAGER_ID'].' | '.$_REQUEST['USES_ID'],
     "UF_TO_KVALIF"=> "1",
     "GROUPS_ID"=> Array(1)
        );
        $arParameters = array(
            'SELECT' => array("UF_*")
        );
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order="asc"), $arfilter, $arParameters);
$is_filtered = $rsUsers->is_filtered;  
while($rsUsers->NavNext(true, "f_")) :
    echo "[".$f_ID."] (".$f_LOGIN.") ".$f_NAME." ".$f_LAST_NAME."<br>"; 
endwhile;
$res = CUser::GetUserGroupList($rsUsers); 
while ($arGroup = $res->Fetch()){ 
  print "<pre>"; print_r($arGroup); print "</pre>"; 
}
?>

<?var_dump($rsUsers);?>
```

Получается следующее:
[image: Полученное]

На рисунке видно что период активности не отображается, хотя они прописаны в админке (DATE_ACTIVE_FROM, DATE_ACTIVE_TO). Подскажите как вывести эти даты и добавить их в свой массив полей?

Answer (score 0):

```
`$res = CUser::GetUserGroupList($f_ID); 
while ($arGroup = $res->Fetch()){ 
  print "<pre>"; print_r($arGroup); print "</pre>"; 
}
`
```

Передавать нужно ID пользователя, вы передаете объект, и не понятно что он вам возвращает